# Is it possible to develop VSTO addins for Office 2007/2010 with Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: ms-office, vsto, add-in

Is it possible to develop VSTO addins for Office 2007/2010 with Visual Studio 2013 ? Seeing only VSTO addins targeting Office 2013 by default in Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is. You can support Office 2007/2010 in the single VSTO add-in.

The [Running Solutions in Different Versions of Microsoft Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb772080(v=vs.120).aspx) article states the following:

*Solutions that were created by using Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio 2013 or Visual Studio 2010 can run in Office 2013, Office 2010, or the 2007 Microsoft Office system. However, the solution can use only those features and APIs that are available in all three versions of Office.*